# Python CountVectorizer(): why do we have to assign CountVectorizer() to a variable in order for this to work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas, text-extraction, countvectorizer

I took this example from the SKLearn website. Here's the initial code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['This is the first document.',
          'This document is the second document.',
          'And this is the third one.',
          'Is this the first document?']

# WORKING: assigning a variable "vectorizer" for CountVectorizer()
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
>>> ['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']

# NOT WORKING
X = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(corpus)
CountVectorizer().get_feature_names()
>>> NotFittedError: Vocabulary not fitted or provided
```

I'm confused at this point. Why do we have to **assign** a `variable` to `CountVectorizer()` if they are **exactly the same thing**?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you create one `CountVectorizer()` object and use it throughout the entire code snippet.

In the second example, the two `CountVectorizers()` refer to two different objects.

Let's walk through the code.

```py
X = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(corpus)
CountVectorizer().get_feature_names()
```

In the first line, we create a new `CountVectorizer()` object, call `.fit_transform()` on it, and then assign the result of the call to `.fit_transform()` to `X`.

In the second line, **we create a different CountVectorizer() object** and call `.get_feature_names()` on it. This object is completely independent from the first one we created; it does not share any memory with the original object. Since you haven't called the `.fit_transform()` method on this one, Python throws an error stating that the vocabulary hasn't been fitted.